# How to update a line in text file with id input

Tags: android, outputstream, android-file

I have a text file is `conten.txt` which has

```
101,1,123
102,1,234
```

I am using Android to update that text file. With a input as "102", I want to update second line with information is "2,234". So it will be

```
102,2,234
```

Finally, the content in text file will be

```
101,1,123
102,2,234
```

Is it possible to do it in Android? This is my current work. However, tt only writes a new line in the file

```
String whole_content="102,2,234";
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "conten.txt");
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
FileOutputStream outputStream;
try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput("conten.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(whole_content.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible! Simply, you could create a string of total file content and replace all the occurrence in the string and write that string to that file again.

```
File log= new File("yourFile");
String search = "102"; //Like you said

try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(log);
    String s;
    String totalStr = "";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(s.contain(search)) {
               s = search + "," + "yourReplaceString"; //You can extract it from your input
            }
            totolStr += s;
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(log);
    fw.write(totalStr);
    fw.close();
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If two string has similar detail as 101,1,123  102,1,234. How can I know which one will replace? Because 1 appear in both. I will base on the id 102. Could you write it in the code

Comment: Check my answer again!

Comment: Try s.indexOf() != -1 instead

Comment: I tried but it still errors. Could you edit your ans.

Comment: Because I look at s.indexOf() != -1 has no input is search.

Comment: No I just write pseudocode, you can see how to use the method in eclipse or another modern IDE. In this situation using s.indexOf(search) != -1